# Sencha Touch - Different path for resources files

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

In my `app.json` I defined `resources` like the following :

```
"resources": [
    "resources/images",
    "resources/icons",
    "resources/startup"
],
```

Instead of just creating a directory `resources` in the build folder and copying the inner folders (images, icons, startup)... the build creates **another** folder `resources` **inside** of the original `resources` folder, and the hierarchy becomes like this :

```
resources/resources/images
resources/resources/icons
resources/resources/startup
```

Where could be the problem ? Can I specify a custom resources folder for the build ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade sencha cmd to version 5.0.2 or higher.

```
$ sencha upgrade
```

*(source)*
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290725-Sencha-Cmd-5.0.1-copies-resources-to-a-wrong-path